# Intercept incoming request implementing HttpRequestHandler and setting user in session -- Play 2.4.6

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to intercept all incoming request having user credential in headers param, once authenticated I try to set user in session. All request coming from external application will have app as code to tell its an external request thus requires an authentication first. But all this is not working as I don't see anything printed in console and also I get context is not present. Please assist. My code below:

I am sending request using post man as below:
[image: Postman request]

#### `application.conf`:

```
play.http.requestHandler=settings.com.xyz.application.ApplicationRequestHandler
```

#### `HttpRequestHandler` implementation:

```
public class ApplicationRequestHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {
    @Inject
    ActiveDirectoryService activeDirectoryService;

    @Override
    public Action createAction(Request request, Method method) {
        return new Action.Simple() {
            @Override
            public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
                String app = request.getHeader("app");
                //ActiveDirectoryService activeDirectoryService = Play.current().injector().instanceOf(ActiveDirectoryService.class);
                if(app != null && app.equals("app")) {
                  if(ctx.current().session().get("username") == null) {
                    String username = request.getHeader("username");
                    String password = request.getHeader("password");
                    System.out.println("#######################################################3" + username + "," + password + "," + activeDirectoryService);
                    if(activeDirectoryService.authenticate(username, password)) {
                        ctx.current().session().put("username", app + username);
                    }
                }
                }
                return delegate.call(ctx);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Action wrapAction(Action action) {
        return action;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us (rather using `curl`) which kind of requests are being made to your application?

Comment: @marcospereira: I have attached an image. I am sending request your post man. Consider that as external system requesting using same url as in post man. Once request handler receive this request and see that this user is not in session then it will authenticate it and put username in session. After that it should be redirected to /getdata controller where actual data will be served. Thanks for looking at this issue.

Comment: My next step would be to print all header values and see if it is transmitted as you want it at all etc.

Comment: I can read header values if I place my getHeader code above return statement, but nothing is getting printed if place it as I have shown, thus I come to know that the code is not executing somehow which am not sure why. I googled and found so many examples but everywhere the implementation is given the way have posted. When call() method is called, who call it, is it called exactly after createAction return??

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible problems here.

#### Some misuse of Postman:

This is the most plausible problem (but see others below). Change your handler code to print all the received headers:

```
public class ApplicationRequestHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {
    @Override
    public Action createAction(Http.Request request, Method method) {
        return new Action.Simple() {
            @Override
            public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {

                // Print all headers
                request.headers().forEach((name, values) -> {
                    System.out.printf("%s: %s \n", name, java.util.Arrays.asList(values));
                });

                String app = request.getHeader("app");
                if(app != null && app.equals("app")) {
                    if(ctx.session().get("username") == null) {
                        String username = request.getHeader("username");
                        String password = request.getHeader("password");
                        System.out.println(username + "," + password);
                    }
                }
                return delegate.call(ctx);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Action wrapAction(Action action) {
        return action;
    }
}
```

The handler above works perfectly to me when using the following request made with `curl`:

```
curl -v -I http://localhost:9000
```

This will print the headers sent by curl so you can check the one received by your application. Then do another request sending the `app` header:

```
curl -v -I -H "app: app" -H "username: marcospereira" -H "password: secret" http://localhost:9000
```

#### The Action was not found

Are you sure that there is a route that match `POST` to `/testapplication/getdata`? If no action was found, your handler will never execute because it **requires** that an action is selected. If the router can't find an action to `POST /testapplication/getdata`, then your handler won't be reached.

Given that, you may reconsider if you need a `HttpRequestHandler` or a [Filter](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaHttpFilters). If you decide to go with filters, I highly suggest that you also [upgrade to Play 2.5.0](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25) because of the [improvements made at the Java version of filters API](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaMigration25#Filter-API).

Comment: In console I see as "[info] - play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)", does that mean I am somehow using scala apis???? In this case do I need to implement play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler instead of play.http.HttpRequestHandler?